# How to access Gunicorn's configuration params from application code?

Tags: python, werkzeug

I have a Werkzeug application served on [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). The script directory layout looks like this:

```
prj/
    __init__.py
    application.py   :which has a WSGI application object "wsgi_app".
    settings_app.py  :settings for werkzeug applicaiton code.
```

Then, I usually use the following command-line to start the Werkzeug application on gunicorn.

```
$ gunicorn --worker-class=gevent --bind=0.0.0.0:80 --workers=5 --daemon [--debug] prj.application:wsgi_app
```

In case of "--debug", gunicorn turns on debugging. Because the "debug" variable of gunicorn affects only gunicorn itself behavior, I also put "DEBUG" variable in "settings_app.py" to change the application's behavior(logging level, template directory, and so on). I feel that is not DRY. Moreover, command-line "debug" option can not override the later "DEBUG" variable.

If gunicorn's configuration variables can be referred in the application code, I can ommit such duplicate copies of variables.

How to access gunicorn's configuration variables from application code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no direct way to be able to import Gunicorn config parameters into your application code.

What you could do is use one of the various config hooks to automatically set the debug variable in your application code.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it.
As you said, gunicorn has some hooks. I may be able to bind a gunicorn configuration class instance to Werkwzug WSGI application by some gunicorn hooks ("post_form" or "pre_request"?). I wiil check it.

Comment: I had forgotten optparse and argparse. Both can parse gunicorn's command-line options and arguments. So, I can get current gunicorn's params in an application code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use optparse before Gunicorn parses args.